# Shopify Liquid + Javascript and if conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shopify, liquid

I am trying to implement a solution to have one header display for the mens section and one other different header for womens.

What I've thought so far is of using localStorage to set a key if a mens/womens page is accessed.

```
<script>
  if (localStorage.getItem("themeSection") === "men") {
    {% sections 'header-group-2' %}
  } else {
    {% sections 'header-group' %}
  }
</script>
```

However I'm struggling when using liquid within js. Does anybody know how to fix this? As this is not working properly at the moment.

Comment: This will not work since you are trying to mix liquid with js. Liquid is rendered server-side and while you are trying to render the sections using client-side logic. An approach that could work for you is to render both sections in liquid with default state as hidden, and then use js to access localstorage to decide which one to show.